# Asnychronous call from server to client in OpaLang

Tags: opa

Scheme for non blocking client to server call is:

```
@async exposed function do_something_on_server() {
  protected_server_job();
}
client function onclick(_) {
  do_something_on_server();
}
<a onclick={onclick}>do it!</a>
```

This call makes use of single HTTP request:

```
https://wkaliszu.pl/_internal_/7821004025888768/rpc_call_async/__do_something_on_server_package.name
```

Can I call a client side code to make a DOM update asynchronously? Adding `@async` seems not to make any difference and I still get extra HTTP request similar to the following:

```
https://wkaliszu.pl/_internal_/7821004025888768/rpc_return/Cl
```

containing `void` value (empty JSON object `{}`).

In case the client call returns the `void` I do not need the value, and making it asynchronous would spare one HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

The @async annotation merely state the call is to executed asynchronously, meaning the caller (client) does not block and wait for the result as with synchronous calls. The async annotation can only be applied to functions returning void, but you still need the initial request from client to server. Only, you do not care about the result. As far as I know the reply request cannot be removed, because that is the Opa implementation.